# C# How to wait for serial port action to finish until doing next read action

Tags: c#, serial-port

first up I try to specify the question. I have 2 devices connected via Serial Port to my Laptop. SerialPort2 is a Sensor, the other is a Motor. I saved a specific Motorposition earlier in the programm. I now want the motor to return to this position and then read the value from the sensor.

Communication with the motor looks like this:

- Send 9-byte-array which stores input information to the motor
- Serial Port answers with a 9-byte-array, according to which command was send. `getPosi()` takes an empty array, fills it with the nessecary information and sends a command which translates to "tell me your current positon", and the answer contains this position.

I catch all answers with `DataReceived` in a global buffer-variable "buf" (which is overwritten after each command i send), and store the position I need later in the programm in another global "M"-varibal (seperate Save-Method). The problem is now, that if i send the command `MoveToSave()` I immediately get an answer, the motor still rotates and the next read() is executed (hence i dont get the value i want).

Here would be the code, if any important info to understand the code is missing, i will add later.

```
    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //move to save
        byte[] E = new byte[9];
        MoveToSave(E);
        byte[] F = new byte[9];
        do
        {
            getPosi(F); //overwrites buf with current position
        }
        while (M != buf)
        //code below is needed to get readable value from sensor
        serialPort2.WriteLine("SR,00,002\r\n");
        string b = serialPort2.ReadLine();
        decimal b1 = decimal.Parse(Regex.Split(b, "SR,00,002,")[1]);
        decimal Diffb = Math.Abs(b1 - caliberMid);
        textBox1.Text = "Mid Wall Thickness: " + Diffb;
        //move to 0
        byte[] D = new byte[9];
        MoveTo0(D);
    }
```

So the question would be, how to realize that the `serialPort2.ReadLine()` is only executed after the motor returned to its saved position. The way I have it currently does not work. It shows me the answer from `getPosi()`, and its the same as my stored "M" but it does not break the loop. There is no answer send by the motor that signals a stop in rotation. Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: Sorry what is the end goal here? You want to compare the motor's _current_ position to its _saved_ position and then if `true` you want to execute `serialPort2.ReadLine()`? Why not place the code you want executed _inside of_ the `dataReceived` handler?

Comment: *Also are you debugging this and stepping through line by line? If you have "M" and "buf" on a watch you should be able to see those values individually at a breakpoint and then you'll be able to see why it's not assessing to true. Just a word of warning though, when pausing your program and reading serial data you wont get an event fire for each character passed to the port. It'll store it in a buffer and then that'll fire the event after you press continue.

Comment: As @J.Doe suggests, you should use the `dataRecieved` event on the `serialPort` class.  It fires every time data is received on the serial port.  In here you'll be able to look for your condition and tell the motor what to do depending on your condition.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the answers so far. The goal is basically to execute the serialPort2.Readline() after the motor stopped rotating and is in his final position. @J.Doe i currently have one dataReceived handler for serialPort3 (the one that catches the answer). Port 3 does not fire anything one its own when its stopped. Port2 would fire until the motor stops. So make one that checks if data is received for Port2? I'll make my way through the debugging first and check the variables again. Thanks again for the tipps! LG, Chris

Comment: @ChristophPoser did you get it all fixed? I have a strong suspicion your comparison isn't set up properly and that's where your trouble lies. After debugging did you find that to be the case?

Comment: And I'm trying to understand here, are you saying both SerialPort3 AND SerialPort2 stop firing anything when the motor stops? If that's the case couldn't you just have a data read handler that stores the data into and array of characters with the expected length and constantly refresh this array with a new input? That way when the motor stops the last thing stored in this array will be info you're looking for correct? Sorry still sorta confused

Comment: @J.Doe The bytearrays did indeed not match. Testing around a bit now. But From another question to another part of the code I got quite a bit of Input in how to write the whole thing cleaner and more eficently. So I'm currently focussed on cleaning up the whole programm, and making it more understandable. This way the current problem might solve as I'll work on the dataReceived handles and the global variables. Otherwise I'll see if i maybe compare the 2 arrays byte by byte in a for loop in a certain time intervall.

Comment: @J.Doe Well motor (Port3) is driving the sensor (Port2). The motor is just firing directly after each command that is send. The sensor just fires when I send a command requesting the position. So while the motor is running and driving the sensor forward, sensor reaches Point B and get pushed in from there until motor reaches point A. Point A is the 0mm setting of the sensor and the saved value of the motor. So I guess while the motor is running I will have the Port2.RequestPosition-Command send in a while loop and when the value does not change anymore i know motor has stopped.